# Переименовывать столбцы и вывести нужное мне количество

Tags: devexpress, wpf, entity-framework, entity

Всех приветствую! 
Вопрос в следующем: 
Есть компонент DevExpress - GridControl. Есть модель БД Entity Fraemwork.
Вывожу данные из БД через модель в GridControl.
Проблема в том, что я не могу переименовывать столбцы и вывести нужное мне количество столбцов. Т.е. в GridControl выводится поля с англ. названиями полей (как в исходной таблице БД), и абсолютно все поля таблицы.

файл .xaml.cs

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
    try
    {   
        List<SHALUNModel.MYTABLE> paList = GetEeeee();                  
        grdMain.ItemsSource = paList; //Мой грид   
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);      
    }
} 
public List<SHALUNModel.MYTABLE> GetEeeee() 
{
    return myApp.CreditResourcesContext.MYTABLEs.OrderBy(ei=>ei.id).ToList();
}
```

Файл .xaml

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grdMain">
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Field1" Header="Поле1"/>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Field2" Header="Поле2"/>
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Field3" Header="Поле3"/>  
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Сам запрос выполняется методом LINQ to SQL.
Соответсвенно SHALUNModel это модель БД сделанная через конструктор Entity Fraemwork, MYTABLE это сущность таблицы из моей БД, id это поле по которому я сортирую результат запроса и grdMain это собственно GridControl в который я вывожу данные.

Вопросы:

1. как можно вывести только три поля указанные в GridControl, а не все 20 по результатам запроса
2. как сохранить название столбцов после выполнения запроса (Поле1, Поле2, Поле3)

Answer (score 1):

```
AutoGenerateColumns="None"
```